# Can we run initial sql in oracle jdbc connection on jetty?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jetty

I have a local jetty java project. I would like to run some sql when the server creates any connections. The connections are configured in a jetty-env.xml file. Im hoping there is some  oracle jdbc property like "run-sql-on-connect" where I can trigger the sql. Essentially I want to alter the session whenever a connection is established. Is there anything in OracleDataSource.connectionProperties like this?

```
<New id="OracleDS_local" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/local</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
            <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:*******</Set>
            <Set name="user">*****</Set>
            <Set name="password">****</Set>
            <Set name="connectionProperties ">
                <Set name="run-sql-on-connect" >alter session sql here</Set>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround/solution (depending on the requirements) would be to use a custom context handler and a related event to perform a separate connection and execute the query you want.

I know it's not an optimal solution but it might do the trick.

Reference:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-11/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html

```
<Configure id='oracledbdemo' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="OracleDS_local" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
...
</Configure>
```

REPLACE WITH

```
<Configure id='oracledbdemo' class="<YOUR_CUSTOM_WebAppContext_HERE">
</Configure>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Im wondering if I go that that level of effort will I find that it gets initialized after the app starts. The issue Im trying to solve is it takes 10 minutes to start and deploy the app. The app uses javalite and active jdbc and it inspects every table on startup using dba views. I suspect the slowness is due to a bug in oracle database and I have read there are some workarounds by altering the session. However the sql must run before acvitejdbc validates the tables on startup or we will still see the slow deployment.